# Test-Driven Development in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, testing, tdd

I'm using CakePHP 2.3 and would like to know how to properly go about building a CakePHP website using test-driven development (TDD). I've read [the official documentation on testing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html), read Mark Story's [Testing CakePHP Controllers the hard way](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/testing-cakephp-controllers-the-hard-way), and watched Mark Story's [Win at life with Unit testing](http://tv.cakephp.org/video/CakeFoundation/2010/12/24/mark_story_-_win_at_life_with_unit_testing/playlist:4d14370c-0610-4e56-a6f2-57a282f0cb67) ([PDF of slides](http://mark-story.com/files/win_at_life_with_unit_testing.pdf)) but am still confused. I should note that I've never been very good about writing tests in any language and don't have a lot of experience with it, and that is likely contributing to my confusion.

**I'd like to see a step by step walkthrough with code examples on how to build a CakePHP website using TDD.** There are articles on TDD, there are articles on testing with CakePHP, but I have yet to find an in-depth article that is about both. I want something that holds my hand through the whole process. I realize this is somewhat of a tall order because, unless my Google-fu is failing me, I'm pretty sure such an article hasn't yet been published, so I'm basically asking you to write an article (or a long Stack Overflow answer), which takes time. Because this is a tall order, I plan to start a bounty on this question worth a lot of points once I'm able to in order to better reward somebody for their efforts, should anybody be willing to do this. I thank you for your time.

Comment: what do you really want I mean how depth. can you give an example projects to help me understand what do you mean than in-depth?

Comment: and also it needs time maybe more than the time that the bonty will end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TDD is a bit of falacy in that it's essentially just writing tests before you code to ensure that you are writing tests.

All you need to do is create your tests for a thing before you go create it. This requires **thought** and analysis of your use cases in order to write tests.

So if you want someone to view data, you'll want to write a test for a controller. It'll probably be something like `testViewSingleItem()`, you'll probably want to `assertContains()` some data that you want.

Once this is written, it **should fail**, then you go write your controller method in order to make the test pass.

That's it. Just rinse and repeat for each use case. This is Unit Testing.

Other tests such as Functional tests and Integration tests are just testing different aspects of your application. It's up to you to **think** and **decide** which of these tests are usefull to your project.

Most of the time Unit Testing is the way to go as you can test individual parts of the application. Usually parts which will impact on the functionality the most, the "Critical path".

This is an incredibly useful TDD tutorial. http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/test-driven-php/

Comment: I appreciate your time and advice! That link is helpful, too. I would still be interested in seeing an in-depth walkthrough of TDD with CakePHP, though.

Comment: There is no real "thing" between TDD and CakePHP. You just learn TDD theory, learn PHP Unit, and then just write some tests. The book has a good chapter on testing. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html

Comment: Also look inside the source code of CakePHP itself. Inside the [`lib/Cake/Test`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/master/lib/Cake/Test/) directory, you'll find all the Unit-tests of the framework itself. You can use those as an example for your own tests and, for example, understand how to create a unit-test to test a Controller or a Model

Comment: I understand where you both are coming from, but if you look at these two questions I've asked ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16448178/937084) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16465952/937084)), you'll see that this is still quite confusing for me, even after reading the documentation. This is why I would like to see a guide.

Comment: This is also worth a mention although I haven't read it. https://leanpub.com/cakephpunittesting

Comment: @DavidYell Well that looks like it may just be what I'm after! Thanks!